# Query is selecting count from joined table

Tags: mysql

I have a shipments table, and a shipments detail table. A shipment generally ships multiple cartons. I am trying to select a count of the shipment table and sum the quantity from the detail table. But my values are being selected from the joined table.

ex. count = 7, when count should be 4 from my shipment table

```
 SELECT ss.tenant_id,
 ss.order_id,
 COUNT(ss.shipment_number),
 SUM(sd.qty_shipped)
 FROM shipment ss
     LEFT JOIN detail sd
         ON ss.id = sd.shipment_id
 GROUP BY
     ss.order_id,
     ss.tenant_id;
```

output -->

```
tenant_id | order_id | count | sum  
-----------+----------+-------+------
        1 |     2573 |     7 | 1350
```

Data set -->

```
shipment
 id  | shipment_number | shipment_status | tracking_number | shipping_cost  
------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------
8332 | 1000048         | confirmed       | 123            | 10.00                    

8333 | 1000049         | confirmed       | 123            | 10.00                   

8334 | 1000050         | confirmed       | 123            | 10.00                  

8335 | 1000051         | confirmed       | 123            | 10.00 


detail
  id   | carton_number | qty_shipped | order_id | shipment_id 
-------+---------------+-------------+----------+------------
 14654 | 1             |         200 |     2573 | 8332 
 14655 | 2             |         200 |     2573 | 8332 
 14656 | 1             |         200 |     2573 | 8333 
 14657 | 1             |         200 |     2573 | 8334 
 14658 | 2             |         200 |     2573 | 8334 
 14659 | 1             |         150 |     2573 | 8335 
 14660 | 2             |         200 |     2573 | 8335
```

Comment: Which values are incorrect and what is your expected results.  Perhaps you just need  `COUNT(distinct ss.order_id)`?

Comment: What values are "doubled" and what are your expected results given your sample data?  The issue is a join that results in a 1-M relationship will cause the 1 records to be multiples for every record in M.  Thus if you count the 1's you'll get 1* the related records in M.  or 7 orders when only 1 was really present.  aggregate before the join or use a distinct on the count.

Comment: The Count and the Sum, both look OKAY to me! in your output.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the wording on my question. The count should be selecting the 4 from shipment, not the 7 from detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add distinct in my count.

```
                select ss.tenant_id,
                ss.order_id,
                count(distinct ss.shipment_number),
                sum(sd.qty_shipped)
                from shipping_shipment ss
                    left join shipping_shipmentdetail sd
                        on ss.id = sd.shipment_id
                GROUP BY
                    ss.order_id,
                    ss.tenant_id;
```